# How to know network mask in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I'm developing a tool for networking and I don't know how to get the network mask of the computer that executes the program. I know I can get the IP by OS library, but I don't know how I could know the mask, Can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I'm using 0.10.* version... I know  there's in 0.11.11 version the option "netmask" on require('os').networkInterfaces(). But I have to use 0.10.* version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always execute `ifconfig` from your node script, then parse the output and extract the netmask parameter for the network interface you're interested in.

You could run `ifconfig interface_name | grep 'inet '`, where interface_name would be the interface you're interested in. Parsing the output of the above should be pretty easy. On OSX, look for the value after 'netmask', on Linux 'Mask:'

Comment: Yeah! It's a solution, but I just wondered if there's other way without root permission, because you have to have this level in debian.

Comment: @user2976034 By default you get command not found because it's not it the user's PATH. You can run ifconfig on debian without root by executing ifconfig from its full path, `/sbin/ifconfig`

Comment: ah! ok, Thank you! I didn't know it!